# Como controlar as bordas em vídeo do Youtube

Tags: css, html5, youtube

Como embedar um video do Youtube sem deixar essa bordar preta dos lados. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de deixar ele com 100% de largura porém com uma altura definida alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: As bordas pretas estão aí porque o vídeo não tem a mesma largura que a tela, e o Youtube até onde sei não deixa você achatar o vídeo. Tens que aumentar a altura do vídeo até que as bordas desapareçam, ou então abrir mão do vídeo ocupar 100% da largura.

Answer (score 2):

Depender da proporção do formato do vídeo.

Se você estiver colocando o player em um formato 4:3 ex: 640x480 e o vídeo for nesse formato, não terá borda.
Agora se o seu player é 16:9 (720p) e seu vídeo 4:3 como no caso da sua foto terá borda.

*(OBS: para ser exato esse player deve estar 21:9 e o seu vídeo 16:9, ambos widescreen mas com proporções diferentes)*

**Para entender formatos de tela:**
Wikipedia : http://goo.gl/ZxTmU4

## **Soluções:**

Você terá sempre um padrão de vídeo? se sim, então coloque o player com as dimensões exatas. No caso a altura que você quer.

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Ipsi5aJzXBc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 width="640"  //largura
 height="480"  //altura
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa borda em alguns vídeos é problema da própria é edição, sendo assim impossível você resolver o problema dimensionando o player, se dimensionar o player por `width` e `height` poderá prejudicar a execução de outros.